# Highcharts in a div container

Tags: html, angularjs, highcharts

I have a problem to show my Highchart in a container div.

In the .html file I have the next code:

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:10px">
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

In my controller I have a function which I create the chart after doing query to the DB and to save the data in the variable media. The chart is created as follows:

```
var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Media'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '..'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Media'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Media: {point.y:.1f}'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Population',
        data: media,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

The "data" are received correctly, the problem is that when I click in a button to call this function and I try to show the chart, appears "http://localhost:8080/graphics**#container**" in my  address bar but the chart doesn't appear till I click the button a second time.

I don't understand why is it happening this and how can I do to show the data in my "first click".

If anyone can help me I will be very grateful.

Thank you!

**SOLVED**

The probrlem was another function which I used to move the scroll. I deleted it and everything works fine!

The fuction was the following:

```
function downScroll(){

    $location.hash('container');
    call $anchorScroll()
    $anchorScroll();

}
```

Comment: use highcharts-ng directive

Comment: I am not sure this helps but check if you defined the controller twice

Comment: try writing whole code in 
$(function () {
 //code here
});

Comment: There is not enough information. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to recreate your problem.